# How to expand the Dirac equation?

Tags: metric-tensor, conventions, dirac-equation, wick-rotation

I've been reading a little bit of the Dirac Equation and I'm a little confussed about how it shall be expaned.

The dirac equation has the form of 
$$i\hbar \gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu} \Psi -mc \Psi = 0$$

I would expand it as $$i\hbar \gamma^{0} \partial^{0} \Psi -i\hbar \gamma^{i} \partial^{i} \Psi = mc \Psi$$
But a lot of papers expand it as
$$i\hbar \gamma^{0} \partial^{0} \Psi +i\hbar \gamma^{i} \partial^{i} \Psi = mc \Psi$$

Comment: What metric tensor did you use? mostly + or mostly -?

Comment: I use (+,-,-,-) for the metric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use the (+---) convention, you should pay attention to the Latin indices for the spatial part.

$$\partial_{i} = -\partial^{i}$$ is all you need, because it immediately follows

$$ \gamma^i \partial_{i} = -\gamma^i\partial^{i}$$